# PCL, creating PointCloud<FPFHSignature33> from vector<FPFHSignature33>?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am updating my PCL FPFH feature code to use the gpu modules. This is all going according to plan, except for the return type.

The original cpu version:

`pcl::FPFHEstimation<PointXYZ, Normal, FPFHSignature33> fpfh_est;`

returns from the `compute` function a:

`PointCloud<FPFHSignature33>`

and when i download the returned data from the gpu function, it is:

```
int stub;
    vector<FPFHSignature33> downloaded;
    fpfhs_gpu.download(downloaded, stub);
```

How can i convert this `vector<FPFHSignature33>` into the `PointCloud<FPFHSignature33>` that the rest of my application needs?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
fpfhs_gpu.download(downloaded, stub);

    for (int i = 0; i < downloaded.size(); i++)
    {
        fpfhs_src.push_back(downloaded[i]);
    }
```

But it is slow, as it loops through every value in the vector. Is there a faster way?